# Angular - Remove item from array on click of that item

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular (v6 to be specific), and trying to build a simple to do list.

I'm able to add items to an array and display in a list but cannot figure out how to delete specific items on click of that item.

Current code deletes the entire array on click. Here's my code:

app.component.html

```
 <h1>To Do List</h1>
  <label for="">What do you need to to?</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="listItem">
  <br>
  <button (click)="addToList()">Add</button>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let toDo of toDoList" (click)="removeFromList($event)">{{ toDo }}</li>
  </ul>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'to-do-list-app';
  listItem = '';
  toDoList = [];

  addToList() {
    this.toDoList.push(this.listItem);
  }

  removeFromList(addedItem) {
    this.toDoList.splice(addedItem);
  }
```

Comment: $event doesn't work like this. You should pass toDo or toDo's index to your function and work with it.

Comment: You got it, that was it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the item index to `splice` and specify that one item is to be removed:

```
<li *ngFor="let toDo of toDoList; let i = index" (click)="toDoList.splice(i, 1)">
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cm3rvt) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks! Although the below options also works, this is the more elegant approach. I just learned this index method, but did not think of it in this project.

Answer (score 0):

On your click function send the object you are removing:

```html
<li *ngFor="let toDo of toDoList" (click)="removeFromList(toDo)">{{ toDo }}</li>
```

And in your function, find the index of the element, and then use splice to remove it

```js
removeFromList(addedItem) {
    var index = this.toDoList.indexOf(addedItem);

    this.toDoList.splice(index, 1); // Removes one element, starting from index
}
```

Comment: This works.  I was passing ($event) instead of (toDO)

Comment: This is bad solution. You have indexes in ngFor, there is no need to find it with indexOf. You get performance overhead and bugs in case of duplicate items.

Answer (score 0):

Splice will remove the item from the array by index (and how many items you want to remove), not by value.

To work with arrays and collections, I would suggest to use https://underscorejs.org/ I know it may be an overkill for this problem, but will be useful for more complex scenarios.

You can add the library to your angular project by running the following command:

```
npm i underscore --save
```

You may want to also add the typings by running:

```
npm i @types/underscore --save-dev
```

Your app.component.ts would then look like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'underscore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'to-do-list-app';
  listItem = '';
  toDoList = [];

  addToList() {
    this.toDoList.push(this.listItem);
  }
  removeFromList(addedItem) {
    this.toDoList = _.without(this.toDoList, addedItem);
  }
}
```

And your app.component.html will look like:

```
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<label for="">What do you need to to?</label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="listItem">
<br>
<button (click)="addToList()">Add</button>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let toDo of toDoList" (click)="removeFromList(toDo)">{{ toDo }}</li>
</ul>
```